# QProcess is stuck

Tags: c++, qt4, mingw

I have the following small application. Running Qt with MinGW compiler in Windows 7

```
#include <QProcess>
#include <QStringList>
#include <iostream>

const int64_t kBuffSize = 2048;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QProcess grep;
  QStringList params;
  params << "-e" << "\".*pas'\"" << "\"Path to file\"";
  grep.start("C:\\MinGW\\msys\\1.0\\bin\\grep.exe", params);
  grep.setReadChannel(QProcess::StandardOutput);
  if (!grep.waitForFinished()) {
    if (grep.state() == QProcess::Running)
      grep.kill();
    return 1;
  }
  std::cout << "ready to read"  << std::endl;
  char buffer[kBuffSize];
  while (grep.readLine(buffer, kBuffSize) > 0) {
    std::cout << buffer;
  }
  if (grep.state() == QProcess::Running)
    grep.kill();
  return 0;
}
```

Despite all efforts, after running this program the only output I get is:

```
QProcess: Destroyed while process still running
```

I don't know if I am doing something wrong, or I am missing something. I have change the `waitForFinished` call for `waitForReadyRead` I setted up the read channel myself, all to no avail. Now I officially need help since I don't want to implement my own grep.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a general fashion, you don't want to run a process and accumulate **all** it's output in a system pipe before trying to read.  This is know to cause deadlocks, especially on Windows.

The system imposes a limit on the buffer size for the pipe. What happens is that the child process (grep) blocks on a write to the pipe because the buffer is full.  It waits for the parent process (you app) to read from the pipe, freeing space in the buffer.  Now, since your applications is in a blocking wait, waiting for the process to finish, they're each waiting after each other.

Because `waitForFinish()` waits at most 30 seconds by default, at the end of 30 seconds, your application breaks the blocking wait and returns, the child process is still running and you kill it.

The solution to this problem is an active read loop to process the child process output as it is generated, ensuring free space in the buffer and thus preventing the deadock.

I'm no expert in Qt, so I'm not sure how to implement this active loop in Qt.  Taking a look at the [documentation for `QProcess`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qprocess.html), I'd say something like:

```
    // Use resizable buffers, unlike the system.
QByteArray stderr;
QByteArray stdout;

    // Give the child process some time to start.
grep.waitForStarted();
do {
        // Read all available data on both output streams.
    stderr += grep.readAllStandardError();
    stdout += grep.readAllStandardOutput();
}
    // Wait 100 ms and keep looping if not finished.
while ( !grep.waitForFinished(100) );

    // Make sure you catch any leftovers.
stderr += grep.readAllStandardError();
stdout += grep.readAllStandardOutput();

// Do something with the buffers.
```

Comment: Note: I've had the same problem with Python's subprocess module.  At  least their document is clear enough on that subject.  The suggested alternative implements such an active loop. (http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.wait)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1) you should probably call waitForStarted() after the start to wait until it's up and running.

2) you don't want to call waitForFinished() near the top, because it'll wait until it's done (defaulting to waiting for 30 seconds).

3) You probably do want to call waitForFinished() at the end after you're done looking for output (on most OSes you need to let the process return a proper exit status and wait for it; I actually am not positive how Qt deals with this, to be honest, and whether you must perform a waitForFinished() in the higher code or whether the lower Qt code will let you ignore this requirement)